# Using promises but actions not being dispatched in order

Tags: react-redux

I have a React/Redux application. The order of operations in my deletePost action are not behaving as I expect. Even thought I am using .then my history push is occurring before my DELETE_POST has finished. The result is that the deleted post displays momentarily after the push.

To summarize... in the action below, the push to '/feed' is redirecting, then calling the componentDidMount() of the '/feed' page which fetches all posts, then the DELETE_POST is updating the state. Shouldn't the DELETE_POST finish then the push would occur?

The image below shows that the GET_POSTS action called by the componentDidMount() after the redirect is occurring before the DELETE_POST action.

```
// Delete Post
export const deletePost = (id, history) => dispatch => {
  axios
    .delete(`/api/posts/${id}`)
    .then(res =>
      dispatch({
        type: DELETE_POST,
        payload: id
      })
    )
    .then(history.push('/feed'))
    .catch(err =>
      dispatch({
        type: GET_ERRORS,
        payload: err.response.data
      })
    );
};
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this:

```
.then(history.push('/feed'))
```

by this:

```
.then(() => history.push('/feed'))
```

`then` requires you to pass a callback as an argument, you were passing a value.